# C - Split a string at the whitespaces

Tags: c, split

I need to split a string where there are spaces (ex string: `Hello this     is an    example string.` into an array of words. I'm not sure what I'm missing here, I'm also curious as to what the best way to test this function is. The only library function allowed is `malloc`.

Any help is appreciated!

```
#include <stdlib.h>

char **ft_split(char *str) {
    int wordlength;
    int wordcount;
    char **wordbank;
    int i;
    int current;

    current = 0;
    wordlength = 0;
    //while sentence
    while (str[wordlength] != '\0') {
        //go till letters
        while (str[current] == ' ')
            current++;
        //go till spaces
        wordlength = 0;
        while (str[wordlength] != ' ' && str[wordlength] != '\0')
            wordlength++;
         //make memory for word
        wordbank[wordcount] = malloc(sizeof(char) * (wordlength - current + 1));

        i = 0;
        //fill wordbank current
        while (i < wordlength - current) {
            wordbank[wordcount][i] = str[current];
            i++;
            current++;
        }

        //end word with '\0'
        wordbank[wordcount][i] = '\0';

        wordcount++;
    }
    return wordbank;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use `strchr()`?

Comment: Or `strtok_s`/`strtok_r`?

Comment: Are you currently doing the "piscine" ?

Comment: Unless you intend to only use it for English, you might want to check out ICU (International Components for Unicode). Other languages can have multi-byte characters (if encoded using standard UTF-8) and words might not be separated by white space, which makes the situation quite complicated. Using the ICU library you can get pointers to the start and end of words easily, without worrying about the gory details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- You do not allocate an array for `wordbank` to point to, dereferencing an uninitialized pointer has undefined behavior.
- Your approach to scanning the string is broken: you reset `wordlength` inside the loop so you keep re-scanning from the beginning of the string.
- You should allocate an extra entry in the array for a trailing null pointer to indicate the end of the array to the caller.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

char **ft_split(const char *str) {
    size_t i, j, k, wordcount;
    char **wordbank;

    // count the number of words:
    wordcount = 0; 
    for (i = 0; str[i]; i++) {
        if (str[i] != ' ' && (i == 0 || str[i - 1] == ' ')) {
            wordcount++;
        }
    }

    // allocate the word array
    wordbank = malloc((wordcount + 1) * sizeof(*wordbank));
    if (wordbank) {
        for (i = k = 0;;) {
            // skip spaces
            while (str[i] == ' ')
                i++;
            // check for end of string
            if (str[i] == '\0')
                break;
            // scan for end of word
            for (j = i++; str[i] != '\0' && str[i] != ' '; i++)
                continue;
            // allocate space for word copy
            wordbank[k] = p = malloc(i - j + 1);
            if (p == NULL) {
                // allocation failed: free and return NULL
                while (k-- > 0) {
                    free(wordbank[k]);
                }
                free(wordbank);
                return NULL;
            }
            // copy string contents
            memcpy(p, str + j, i - j);
            p[i - j] = '\0';
        }
        // set a null pointer at the end of the array
        wordbank[k] = NULL;
    }
    return wordbank;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to `malloc()` wordbank too. You can count the number for words, and then

```
wordbank = malloc((count + 1) * sizeof(*wordbank));
if (wordbank == NULL)
    return NULL;
```

**Note**: `sizeof(char)` is 1 by definition. And `sizeof *pointer` is always what you want.

Comment: Yeah, this `sizeof(*pointer)` trick looks cool, and I've seen people recommend it to others the way you do, but how can one dereference an uninitialized pointer? That's undefined behavior, as far as I know...

Comment: @ForceBru `sizeof` does not evaluate arguments when it is not needed. See [DEMO](http://ideone.com/ASzi4X)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY, indeed, that's actually rather clever. Thanks!

Comment: `wordbank` should be allocated to one more than the number of words and a null pointer should be stored in the last position to the caller can determine the number of words from the array contents.